# Служба Windows, не работает метод, дебаггер молчит

Tags: c#, служба

Добрый день. Служба Windows установлена под правами Локальной системы (пробовал и под правами текущего пользователя с админ правами). Нужно было сделать скриншот рабочего стола. Нашел такие методы:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Делает скриншот рабочего стола
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Bitmap img</returns>
    public static Bitmap GetScreenshot()
    {
        Graphics graph = null;

        var bmp = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

        return bmp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загружает изображение на хостинг
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
    /// <returns>Ссылка на изображение</returns>
    public static string PostToImg(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "key", "3d5907509d22a3130787a91bbb3c9189" },
                { "image", Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()) }
            };
            string debug = values.ToString();
            byte[] response = w.UploadValues("http://imgur.com/api/upload.xml", values);
            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(response));
            return (string)xDocument.Root.Element("original_image");
        }
    }
```

Вызывается все это дело так: string @out = PostToImg(GetScreenshot());

В WinForms (или WPF) все прекрасно работает, подскажите почему может не работать в службе?

Comment: Дак, как тогда сделать-то? Прошу подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем для Vista, 7, 8, по материалам стековерфлов, это сделать нереально использовав только службу.

Comment: Вы можете, однако, держать мелкое приложение, бегущее с правами (и в UI-сессии) нужного пользователя, и в нужный момент передать ему команду от службы.